# Writing CMake for a Qt fetch with SFML

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I want to make a Qt and SFML program which is also cross-platfrom (mainly for Linux and Windows), so I don't want to have any installations, and any downloads required for the user to make when trying to set up this program.

I have some dependencies for SFML, which in the case of Linux, the user can easily download using `sudo apt install ...`. So I want to fetch Qt from the web, without system-wide installation.

I don't know what is the proper way to do this, but after some searching on the web for SFML and Qt fetch-based CMake programs, I have this CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(PathFinder VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

file( TO_CMAKE_PATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt" LOC_PATH )
if( EXISTS "${LOC_PATH}" )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "You cannot build in a source directory (or any directory with "
                         "CMakeLists.txt file). Please make a build subdirectory. Feel free to "
                         "remove CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles." )
endif()

# Fetch the package
find_package( Qt6 6.4.2 QUIET )

if( NOT Qt6_FOUND )

    # Set Ninja for compilation
    set( CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja" CACHE STRING "CMake generator" FORCE )

    # Initial message
    message( STATUS "Qt 6.6.1 not found. Downloading and configuring Qt..." )

    # Download and extract archive of Qt 6.6.1
    set( QT_VERSION "6.6.1" )
    set( QT_ARCHIVE_URL "https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.6/${QT_VERSION}/submodules/qtbase-everywhere-src-${QT_VERSION}.zip" )
    set( QT_ARCHIVE_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qtbase-everywhere-src-${QT_VERSION}.tar.xz" )
    set( QT_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qtbase-everywhere-src-${QT_VERSION}" )
    message( STATUS "Downloading the package from the official repository..." )
    file( DOWNLOAD ${QT_ARCHIVE_URL} ${QT_ARCHIVE_FILE}
          SHOW_PROGRESS
          EXPECTED_HASH SHA256=a88bc6cedbb34878a49a622baa79cace78cfbad4f95fdbd3656ddb21c705525d )
    message( STATUS "Unpacking the release..." )
    execute_process( COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xvf ${QT_ARCHIVE_FILE}
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} 
                     OUTPUT_QUIET
    )

    # Configure Qt (skip building of useless modules)
    set( QT_BUILD_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qt-build" )
    file( MAKE_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    message( STATUS "Configuring..." )
    execute_process( COMMAND ${QT_SOURCE_DIR}/configure -prefix ${QT_BUILD_DIR}
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )

    # Check if system supports parallelization
    if( DEFINED ENV{NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS} )
        set( JOBS_OPTION "-j$ENV{NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}" )
    elseif( DEFINED ENV{PROCESSOR_COUNT} )
        set( JOBS_OPTION "-j$ENV{PROCESSOR_COUNT}" )
    else()
        set( JOBS_OPTION "" )
    endif()

    # Use -j option to compile if possible (qt is very big)
    if( JOBS_OPTION )
        message( STATUS "Compiling with parallelization..." )
        execute_process( COMMAND ninja ${JOBS_OPTION}
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    else()
        message( STATUS "Compiling without parallelization..." )
        execute_process( COMMAND ninja
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    endif()

    # Set necessary environment variables to use Qt
    set( ENV{QTDIR} ${QT_BUILD_DIR} )
    set( ENV{PATH} ${QT_BUILD_DIR}/bin:$ENV{PATH})

else()
    message( STATUS "Qt 6.4.2 found in the system." )
endif()

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.6.x)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(PathFinder src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(CMakeSFMLProject PRIVATE sfml-graphics Qt5::Widgets)

target_compile_features(PathFinder PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET PathFinder
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<EQUAL:${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P},8>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:CMakeSFMLProject>
        VERBATIM)
endif()

install(TARGETS PathFinder)
```

But I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
Generator 
Ninja does not support instance specification, but instance           
C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community was specified. 
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage         
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Being able to download sfml and Qt locally without installing system wide can be done using vcpkg in manifest mode. I would recommend a proper package manager as opposed to writing fetching code in cmake scripts.

Comment: How would you do it? How would the cmake file change? Sorry I am a little bit lost...

Comment: Ah! It's actually not that hard, but there's a few components to learn. Firstly, vcpkg is gonna write instruction on how to import the package to CMake, so you can base yourself on the instructions. Now, to write a manifest file, here's a full tutorial on how to do a project using vcpkg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/consume/manifest-mode?tabs=cmake%2Cbuild-cmake

Comment: Why do you set `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable? This variable reflects the [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) which is set in the command line or automatically selected. By setting the variable you only confuse CMake about generator which is used.

Comment: Speaking to Qt, personally, I don't think that this is something that you should do, either for yourself or for your downstream users. Qt is very mature and has extremely good CMake support. This is definitely a problem that can be solved with documentation... "Install Qt according to your OS and/or package manager instructions".